# Voice to Text recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am a beginner in Android development. Is there any possibility to write a speech to text software that could access Googles network based back-end voice to text system ?

Comment: Yes of course there is a big possibility for this to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try the recognizer intent...check out the links below and see if it answers your query:
[sample code for voice recognition](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html)

[voice recognizer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, Google Voice API is closed. They don't allow to used their API to make software for others.

There are other companies that can provided speech recognition software as a product (you install in your server) or as a service (send audio and receive text).

Comment: Did you check 0cool answer? You should comment there if he is wrong. Besides that, you should not answer two times, next time please include both in one answer